# local.ERROR: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com

Tags: php, laravel, apache, email, xampp

I am trying to send email locally from my `Laravel` website. But I am getting the error

> local.ERROR: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
>    #10060]

Here is my `.env` file mail part

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=arafat@lasermedicalbd.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=app_specific_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I have already tried with changing `MAIL_DRIVER` with `sendmail` and `MAIL_PORT` with `465` and `250`

Still got the same error. I have googling about the error and change in my code but error not solved yet.

Any body can Help please ?

Comment: are you sure `arafat@lasermedicalbd.com` mail is hosted on smtp

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta...`arafat@lasermedicalbd.com` is a `G-suite` email. Is there any configuration need to change in `.env` file for `G-suite` email?

Comment: what is in you `app/config.php` file

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta...it's in `config/app.php` file...
`'mail_host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),`

Answer (score 0):

In your local PC(with xampp/wamp/lamp) try the following steps if you want to work with Gmail

1. https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps give permission for lesser secured app
2. change your config like this

   MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com Or 173.194.65.108
    MAIL_PORT=587
    MAIL_USERNAME=expense@blabla.com
    MAIL_PASSWORD=secret
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
3. here important is driver - sendmail
4. Clear you config -

   php artisan view:clear
   php artisan route:clear
   php artisan config:clear
   php artisan cache:clear
   php artisan config:cache
5. Now try to send the mail , it should work if your network administrator did not blocked it[unintentionally! In my cases he even do not know for which change it stopped to sending mail]
6. I use these steps with laravel 5.2 and it worked fine but recently something is changed by either google Or My network administrator so its not sending mail from xampp but working fine in shared hosting.